# Angular 6 - ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular and Typescript and cannot get to the bottom of this console error: "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined"

I'm calling a silly service that returns a Chuck Norris joke. This actually works OK. I'm getting Typescript console errors however.

I've reproduced here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-chuck

Many thanks for looking.

**data.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { DataModel } from './data.model';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  constructor( private http: HttpClient ) { }

  chuckUrl = 'https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random';

  getChuck() {
      return this.http.get<DataModel>(this.chuckUrl);
  }

}
```

**data.model.ts**

```
 export class DataModel {
    public category: any;
    public icon_url: string;
    public id: string;
    public url: string;
    public value: string;
}
```

**data.component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from './data.service';
import { DataModel } from './data.model';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-data',
    templateUrl: './data.component.html'
})

export class AppData implements OnInit {
    constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

    joke: DataModel;

    ngOnInit() {

        this.dataService.getChuck()
            .subscribe(
                (data: DataModel ) => {
                  if (data.category != 'explicit') {
                    this.joke = data;
                  } 
                }
            ); 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Just use

```
<div>{{ joke?.value }}</div>
```

Your `joke` object doesn't have the value until the API response arrives. Thus  use `?` to apply the null check until the response arrives.

Comment: Thanks Prachi, you nailed it. I'll not forget that one again.

Comment: how i can solve this issue in dynamic object ?, my html look like this  <div>{{ joke['xyz' + index] }}</div>,  '?' solution not works here

Answer (score 5):

You can use *ngIf until getting resopnse

below is the sample,

```
<div *ngIf="joke">{{ joke.value }}</div>
```

Comment: Immediately after register into my application, need to update profile data. But in the beginning the model.address.postalCode is null. If i use <div *ngIf="model.address">, input filed will not display. What can I do for that ?

Answer (score -3):

Angular 7 - ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

You can check for the object value by using the `?` operator.

Example:

```
<div> {{ joke?.value }} </div>
```

Comment: copy-cat what so ever