# Cannot read property 'visit' of undefined

Tags: angular

suddenly angular shows starting an error. this appears while compiling at the initial stage and then onwards the whole screen is blank. Not sure for the reason?

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'visit' of undefined
    at convertPropertyBinding (compiler.js:25883)
    at eval (compiler.js:28386)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at createUpdateStatements (compiler.js:28382)
    at eval (compiler.js:28357)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at ViewBuilder._createNodeExpressions (compiler.js:28354)
    at ViewBuilder.build (compiler.js:27591)
    at eval (compiler.js:27590)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

version details:

```
Angular CLI: 1.7.3
Node: 6.11.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.2.9
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cdk: 5.2.4
@angular/cli: 1.7.3
@angular/material: 5.2.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/core: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.3.2
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.2.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.10.2
@schematics/angular: 0.3.2
@schematics/package-update: 0.3.2
typescript: 2.5.3
webpack: 3.11.0
```

Please help!

UPDATE :

By mistake, there are some "/" written just before the variable in curly braces. since the HTML is so long didn't notice this.

It was written as below which produce an error

```
{{ ////price }}
```

Here, I am concerned for the error because from the console error beginner like me can't even think that this could be an issue!

Comment: Could you share your tsconfig.json configurations? and did you made any recent changes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 6 - ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51632397/angular-6-error-typeerror-cannot-read-property-value-of-undefined)

Comment: @ChandanYS - I have updated the question with my mistake.

Comment: @Newbie Rather than editing your question, post an answer (to your own question) and mark it as accepted, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for writing an update! This actually was a problem in my case. Saved me so much time

Answer (score 2):

Since the code was working earlier and all of a sudden it started showing an error, can you follow the following steps :

1) Delete Node_Modules

2) run : npm cache clean --force

3) run : npm install

I believe it should work then, faced similar issues earlier.

Comment: it doesn't help. trying to update angular packages using `ng update`